# How do I make googletest output results like PHPUnit / rspec?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, phpunit, rspec2, googletest

The [googletest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) output by default is very verbose.

I want to see a much more concise output like that of PHPUnit or rspec. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't really like the output of gtest either. Here is how to present it in pretty dot format:

https://gist.github.com/elliotchance/8502845